# How can i get a pair of buttons to appear in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

So I have this assignment for class and I'm stuck trying to figure out a way to make two `button`s that I intentionally made invisible, appear after a start `button` is clicked. The start button would be clicked and then the after clicking 3 cards, the button Hold and Draw will appear

Sorry if this is vague, i'm new to `JavaScript` and very new to StackOverflow :

`JavaScript`:

```
function onCardClick( cardNum ) 
    {
        if ( cardToggle[cardNum-1] ) // Is the card cycling?
        {
            console.log("Card index "+CardsShown[cardNum-1]+" clicked.");
            console.log("Before spl: "+indexArray);
            indexArray.splice(indexArray.indexOf(CardsShown[cardNum-1]), 1);
            console.log("After spl: "+indexArray);
        }
        else if ( CardsShown[cardNum-1] != -1 )
        {
            indexArray.push(CardsShown[cardNum-1]);
            indexArray.sort(sortNumber);
            console.log("After push: "+indexArray);
        }
        cardToggle[cardNum-1] = !cardToggle[cardNum-1];
    }

    function showButton 
    {
        if( ) {
        document.getElementById("buttonVisibility").style.visibility="visible";
        }
    }

    function sortNumber(a,b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
```

`HTML`:

```
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome To The game</h1>
    <div class="stage">
        <ul id="card">
            <li id="card1" onclick="onCardClick(1)"><a></a></li>
            <li id="card2" onclick="onCardClick(2)"><a></a></li>
            <li id="card3" onclick="onCardClick(3)"><a></a></li>
            <li id="card4" onclick="onCardClick(4)"><a></a></li>
            <li id="card5" onclick="onCardClick(5)"><a></a></li>
            <button onclick="onCardClick(1); onCardClick(2); onCardClick(3); onCardClick(4); onCardClick(5);">Start</button>
            <button id="buttonVisibility">Hold</button>
            <button id="buttonVisibility">Draw</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of bugs in your code like,

there is no parenthesis `()` with `showButton` function

```
function showButton (){
//------------------^ should add parenthesis
```

`if` has no expression inside the `showButton()` eg.

```
if( /here should be some expression/ ) {
```

The  `cardToggle` is not defined anywhere in your above code.

First make all the these things correct, and see what the result will come.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I can debug the program surely but i just need some pointers on how to make the two buttons appear.